# Problem with appstreamcli when running apt update

Tags: debian, apt, upgrade

I had a problem with debian testing today when I was running an apt update with following return:

```
E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success 'if /usr/bin/test -w /var/cache/app-info -a -e /usr/bin/appstreamcli; then appstreamcli refresh-cache > /dev/null; fi'
E: Sub-process returned an error code
```

Comment: Hello, and welcome to U&L.  You should probably reformulate this into both a question and an answer separately.  Move the solution into an Answer below, and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

After Googling I found some people saying that removing the package appstream will fix the problem.

This solution will work but in many cases this approach will remove packages that you may not want to remove.

An alternate solution is to comment the three last lines in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50appstream` file like this:

```
...
#APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success {
#    "if /usr/bin/test -w /var/cache/app-info -a -e /usr/bin/appstreamcli; then appstreamcli refresh-cache > /dev/null | true; fi";
#};
```

and then save the file and run `apt-get update` again.

After running a system upgrade there is a chance that the package appstream will have a upgrade that can fix this error and a message like this may appear:

```
Configuration file '/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50appstream'
  ==> Modified (by yourself or by a script) since the installation.
  ==> The package distributor has released an updated version.
    What do you want to do? Your options are:
     Y or I: install the version of the maintainer package
     N or O: keep the currently installed version
       D: Show differences between versions
       Z: start a shell to examine the situation
```

You should say Y to upgrade the file you have modified.

I'm posting this to help others that may search for this error.

Answer (score 4):

```
apt-get clean
```

Emptying the apt cache seems to have solved it for me too.  Then I could run

```
apt-get update
```

without any problem or warning.

Edit: Maybe I was too fast. After cleaning the cache the error was gone, but later it occurred again.

Comment: I'm confused; did you need to run the first two commands, or was emptying the apt cache sufficient?

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem while recovering from a failed update to Ubuntu 20.04. Based on answers elsewhere, I moved appstreamcli out of the way:

```
sudo mv /usr/bin/appstreamcli /root
```

After that,

```
sudo apt update
```

worked without a problem.

I then did

```
sudo apt upgrade
```

and finally

```
sudo apt install --reinstall appstream
sudo rm /root/appstreamcli
```

This resolved the deadlock. I then did have several "kept back" packages to deal with manually, but that was straightforward (if rather tedious).

Answer (score 0):

Use these commands for the solution:

```
sudo chmod a+rwx /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50appstream
sudo gedit use /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50appstream
```

then put in the comment last 3 lines of the file,
Like this:

```
#APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success {

#. "if /usr/bin/test -w /var/cache/app-info -a -e /usr/bin/appstreamcli; then appstreamcli refresh-cache > /dev/null | true; fi";

#};
```

then again do:

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get upgrade
```

and in that

```
Configuration file '/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50appstream'

 ==> Modified (by you or by a script) since installation.

 ==> Package distributor has shipped an updated version.

   What would you like to do about it?  Your options are:

    Y or I: install the package maintainer's version

    N or O: keep your currently-installed version

      D: show the differences between the versions

      Z: start a shell to examine the situation

 The default action is to keep your current version.

*** 50appstream (Y/I/N/O/D/Z) [default=N] ? y

Installing new version of config file /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50appstream ...
```

Give Y and press Enter for the new updated file.

Answer (score 0):

> grep -Rnw '/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/' -e 'Post-Invoke-Success'

```
/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/15update-stamp:1:APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success {"touch /var/lib/apt/periodic/update-success-stamp 2>/dev/null || true";};
/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50command-not-found:14:APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success {
/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20packagekit:11:APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success {
/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99update-notifier:2:APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success {"/usr/lib/update-notifier/update-motd-updates-available 2>/dev/null || true";};
```

In my case, it is `50command-not-found`.

So edit the file accordingly.